# ios eureka custom cell with array cell type

Tags: ios, swift

I am using [eureka](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/) for my ios form builder. My problem is for example i have this kind of data

```
{"Large": 10, "Medium": 5, "Small": 7}
```

and i wanted to display the data like a chart. So I created custom cell to display the chart. I tried to create custom cell with array cell type, but it is not working. The error says that my array does not conform to protocol Equatable. So is there any solution so i can pass my data in array type to a eureka cell ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I got the solution. I convert the array to NSMutableArray and I passed it to my Eureka custom cell